# Error File \endcsname when adding table to tex file

Tags: sharelatex

As my last question might show i have problems compiling my thesis with latex.
I have thus started to rebuild the tex file part to part and have realised that the errormessages with missing \endcsname start when I'm adding a table to the tex file.
My code is attached. any ideas how to resolve this?

Any help is deeply appreciated and welcome

Thanks

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{etex} 

\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in]{geometry} 

\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage[british]{babel}

\usepackage{dsfont} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 

\usepackage{booktabs} 

\usepackage[hang,bottom,stable,multiple]{footmisc} 

\usepackage{appendix} 

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[margin=10pt, font=small, labelfont=bf, labelsep=endash]{caption}

\usepackage{chngcntr} 

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{amsthm} 

\usepackage{thmtools} 

\usepackage{setspace} 

\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage{datetime} 

\usepackage{graphicx,listings,xcolor,textcomp} 

\usepackage{hyperref} 

\usepackage{xparse} 

\usepackage{cleveref} 

\usepackage{arydshln} 

\usepackage{array,hhline} 

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\usepackage{rotating} 

\usepackage{tabularx} 

\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{{Images/}}

\usepackage{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}

\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={((},close={))}}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{blablabla}
    \begin{tabular}{rrr}
    \toprule
    \textbf{ } & \textbf{blablabla} & \textbf{blab} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{blubb} & d \\
          & s & s \\
          & s,s & kjasdsad \\
          & Sasdas & /sS, f  \\
    \textbf{j} & j& j\\
          & jj& j\\
          & j& j\\
    \textbf{j} & j& j\\
          & j& j\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{Source:\citet{hg}}%
\end{table}%
```

Comment: You forgot the pair `\begin{document}`-`\end{document}`…

Comment: Please make your example (1) compile (so you need `\begin{document}... \end{document}`), and (2) minimal (only include preamble necessary to reproduce the problem).

Comment: Does the problem go away if you change the `\label` so it does not include a macro? e.g. `\label{source:hg}`? Not the problem but you are loading packages multiple times. (You load `graphicx` at least three times, for example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from yout citation command in `\label` at the end. A label is pure text. It's a way to make cross-references in your document, not to reference or cite whatever. If you replace your label with, say `\label{Source: hg}`, it works fine:[image]

Also, don't load `amsmath` if you load `mahtools`: the latter does it for you.